# impossibly possible...in one word

Tags: expressions

My son has modified a car that he considers to be capable to do things that it shouldn't or more-so that he uses it for purposes it shouldn't withstand but does. He can't remember the word he thought of that totally describes this conundrum, if you will. It shouldn't, but it does. I suggested sin but he scoffed! Do-able but not do-able. Impossibly possible.

Comment: I suppose *paradoxical* is too "generic", and you specifically mean something along the lines of *capable of transcending its own design limits*.

Comment: *miraculous*?..

Comment: This question may already have an answer here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234594/something-that-is-impossible-but-has-happened

Comment: Something like this? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9yHl24QynOM

Answer (score 1):

Incredible?  Miraculous?

You wanted an adjective -- may I suggest some nouns?  Super-clunker.  Energizer bunny.  The car of nine lives.

Answer (score 0):

- **limitless**: (without limits)
- **boundless**: *boundless possibilities*

Answer (score -1):

> Magic.

There is no way his car just took that corner, it must be magic!